# i wanna know if a member of array is equal to '\' but it gives error

Tags: c++

this is my code.i wanna know if a member of array is equal to '' but it gives error
this is the errors:
missing closing quote
expected a ')'
expected an statement

```
 #include<iostream>
#include<istream>
using namespace std;
float calculator(char** chart, int row, int cul) {
    int current_row, before_row=0;
    float masahat=0,temp=0;
    for (int c = 0; c < cul; c++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            if (chart[r][c] != '.') {
                temp = row - r-1;
                if (chart[r][c] == '_')
                {
                        masahat += temp;
                }
                if (chart[r][c] == '/')
                {
                        temp += 0.5;
                        masahat += temp;
                    
                }
                if (chart[r][c] == '\' )
                {
                        temp -= 0.5;
                        masahat += temp;
                
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    return masahat;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`\` is an escape character, you should double it if you want a single backslash.

```
 if (chart[r][c] == '\\' )
```

The reason that `\` is special is that it's used for *escape sequences* like `\n` for the newline character, `\t` for the tab character and `\'` for the single quote character.

Comment: You could also use a raw string literal.